# Count cell if anther cell is non blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If cell B is not empty then it should check it belongs to which bridge & I want the count in D column.

Can any one plz help how to use countifs function with non blankcell.

[image]

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"<>")`

Comment: Hi @sinthol sasi, have you had a chance to read my answer? Did you have any questions?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use `COUNTIFS` with two criteria ranges.

[image: Demonstration of finished result]

In the demonstration above, I'm using formulas in the `E` column. The text in the `G` column is only there to illustrate what formula I'm using.

Let's break down the formula I'm using in `E2`

- `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,D2,$B:$B,"<>")`
- `$A:$A` is the first criteria range, so we're looking through your entire "Bridge" column
- `D2` is the criteria it must meet to count, in this case we're saying it has to match the text shown in `D2` (which is the text "GA" in this example)
- `$B:$B` is the second criteria range, so we're looking through your entire "LTE Site ID" column
- `"<>"` is the criteria it must meet to count, in this case the special code `"<>"` means "not blank" (if you instead put `"example1"` it'd only count 1 matching result in this example.)

Once both criteria are met, it adds to the count.